# how to pass data from custom module form to stock_picking_form with type 'delivery Order' in odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

i'm trying to custom material order module, so what i did is:
-new material_order model

```
class order_order(osv.osv):

_name = 'order.order'

...
...

def action_receive_products(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    '''
    This function returns an action that display internal move of given order ids.
    '''
    assert len(ids) == 1, 'This option should only be used for a single id at a time'
    picking_id = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context).picking_id.id
    res = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'stock', 'view_picking_form')
    result = {
        'name': _('Delivery Order'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': res and res[1] or False,
        'res_model': 'stock.picking',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': picking_id,
        'context': context,

    }

    return result

class order_line():
...
...
```

what I need to do is:

1. how to pass my custom's model fields to stock_picking_form when action_recieve_product().
2. link that order to warehouse(stock.picking) as 'Delivery Orders' so that can be checked for availability and can be transfered to the requster location (as same as sale order)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: - when performing  action_receive_products() i got blank view_picking_form, it's working in v 7.0 but stock picking and stock move are more complicated in v 8.0
the question is how to pass the fields values to view_picking_form in v 8.0 ?

Comment: I used the same code in V8, except in `'view_id': res and res[1] or False,` I used `'view_id': res[1],`.

Comment: thanks alot, but it did't worked, i think the problem somewhere else